# Why are div, ldiv and lldiv not templates?

Tags: c++, cmath, c++20

According to [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/div), there are

```
std::div_t     div( int x, int y );
std::ldiv_t    div( long x, long y );
std::lldiv_t   div( long long x, long long y );
std::ldiv_t   ldiv( long x, long y );
std::lldiv_t lldiv( long long x, long long y );
```

two div in `<cinttypes>`

I would prefer to have seen

```
template<typename t>
std::div_t<T> div(T x, T y);
template<>
std::div_t<int> div(int x, int x)
{
  // implementation here
}
```

Thoughts?

Comment: The final `std::div<int>` should be `std::div_t<int>`, right?

Comment: What actually baffles me is that these functions exist - yes, division and modulo are often calculated together at hardware level, but virtually any production-ready compiler that I know of is already able to exploit this fact and perform the calculation just once if the C code performs both the division and the modulo.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: "*virtually any production-ready compiler that I know of*" Do you know the status of "production-ready compilers" from *twenty years* ago? Because these were C++98 functions. I rather suspect compiler quality was quite different back then.

Comment: Fair enough. I actually didn't know that they ever existed, so I thought that they were a recent addition, hence my confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean you would like to use template specializations instead of overloading? That's not a good idea.

First of all, what if I use a type that has a conversion operator to `long`? Well, none of the specialization is going to get chosen, because they are only taken when there is an exact match, and that type is not part of them. So I have to use a `static_cast`. This is not the case with operator overloading, where such a conversion is allowed and will happen.

Second of all, what advantage do you gain by specializing like that? You still have to write the same implementation for each specialization. In addition, you can't easily write the implementation in a source file.

The only advantage I could see is that it is much easier to take the address of a specific version of the function, as with templates you would do `&std::div<int>` instead of `static_cast`ing to the right overload.

Here a generic solution would be much more appropriate, because there is some duplication between those functions. Maybe something like this:

```
template<typename T>
concept Integral = std::is_integral_v<T>;

template <Integral T>
struct cdiv_t {
    T quot{};
    T rem{};
};

constexpr auto cdiv(Integral auto x, Integral auto y) noexcept {
    return cdiv_t{x / y, x % y};
}
```

Comment: `concept bool` is obsolete; just use `concept`.

Comment: @Yakk Nice! Thanks for the info